# Knocked out my own admin recongizion on my own site

Tags: 6

I have Drupal 6  site. In deleting spammers I accidently knocked myself out. Can I reclaim admin on my own site? Help.

Comment: Did you block or did you delete the admin account?

Comment: I accidently deleted myself.

Comment: Then the only way is that suggested by Prem Ababd. For more information, check out the post by [Wolfflow](http://drupal.org/node/253124) on drupal.org.

Answer (score 3):

If u are able to create account,create it and in the database for the **'users'** table update **'1'** to the **'uid'** field for the account you created and if you are unable to create a account then create a account manually in the database

```
INSERT INTO users (uid, name, pass) VALUES ('1', 'yourname',> md5('yourpassword'));
```

Comment: relatively new to drupal i appreciate your suggestion

Comment: But is there other ways too?

Comment: u dont kno how to follow the answer??

Comment: Not really I m a newbie

Comment: Do u kno to create a account? or else post the url of your site.

Comment: http://mcreegan.mayfirst.org/

Answer (score 0):

Default method should be to backup entire page before mass operations, and then restore it in case of failure. If you cannot do it on your own, your hosting company probably have nightly backups they can restore for you if you ask them.

If that's not the case, but you can access SQL console or SQL web admin tool, see [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73518/knocked-out-my-own-admin-recongizion-on-my-own-site#73519).

If you can't access SQL console directly, but have file access, you can put SQL code in settings.php wrapped in [db_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7), but be *extremely* careful, as it gets executed on almost every page hit.